# Can't install @apollo/client

Tags: reactjs, npm, apollo

I have a problem whenever I try to install the @apollo/client

I do:

```
npm install @apollo/client
```

And i get the following result in the terminal:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

**I tried deleting both node_modules and package-lock and npm installing again but I still run into the same error.**

This is the log (if it helps you):

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   '/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/bin/node',
0 verbose cli   '/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/bin/npm',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '@apollo/client'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.0.3
2 info using node@v15.0.1
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:file:/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
8 timing config:load:file:/Users/************/dev/twitterlike/client/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:file:/Users/************/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 4ms
19 verbose npm-session a83a368ebfce0eee
20 timing npm:load Completed in 10ms
21 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
22 timing idealTree:init Completed in 592ms
23 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
24 silly idealTree buildDeps
25 silly fetch manifest @apollo/client@*
26 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
27 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@apollo%2fclient 910ms (from cache)
28 silly fetch manifest graphql@^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0
29 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graphql 68ms (from cache)
30 silly placeDep ROOT @apollo/client@3.2.5 OK for: client@0.1.0 want: *
31 silly placeDep ROOT graphql@15.4.0 OK for: @apollo/client@3.2.5 want: ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0
32 timing idealTree Completed in 1588ms
33 timing command:install Completed in 1590ms
34 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined
34 verbose stack     at Arborist.[canPlaceDep] (/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1284:15)
34 verbose stack     at Arborist.[placeDep] (/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1061:36)
34 verbose stack     at Arborist.[placeDep] (/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1212:41)
34 verbose stack     at /Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:766:46
34 verbose stack     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
34 verbose stack     at Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:766:8)
34 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:202:7)
34 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
34 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:121:5)
34 verbose stack     at async install (/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:40:5)
35 verbose cwd /Users/************/dev/twitterlike/client
36 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
37 verbose argv "/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/bin/node" "/Users/************/.nvm/versions/node/v15.0.1/bin/npm" "install" "@apollo/client"
38 verbose node v15.0.1
39 verbose npm  v7.0.3
40 error Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined
41 verbose exit 1
```

I tried to search my issue, but I haven't seen anything that change the current situation.

Hope you can help me out.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved the issue !**

I had my bash to automatically update node to the latest version, which in my case was the **15.0.1** (which is including the latest futures). However, it causes some problems when trying to install **NOT** only @apollo/client, but also @material-ui/core, icons and so on...

So, i switched from my current node version to **14.15.0** (Recommended for most users, as nodejs says) using:

```
nvm install 14
```